# Has this adjacency matrix been evaluated incorrectly or am I making a mistake?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

A task I have been given is to work out the adjacency matrix for this graph:

[image]

I worked out the adjacency matrix and consulted the solution which was provided to me. This is it:

[image]

What confused me is that it states 3,5 (3 along the top, 5 along the side) is connected but 3,6 is not? Is this a mistake or am I at fault? Can node 3 be connected to node 5 through another node?

Comment: It seems to be a mistake. You have the right idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution provided is mistaken: position $(i,j)$ in the matrix is $1$ if and only if there is an *edge* connecting $i$ and $j$, not a chain of edges. In your graph, there is no edge between $3$ and $5$, only a chain $3 - 7 - 5$ which does not count for adjacency. The matrix also misses that position $(3, 5)$ is $1$, and possibly others (I haven't checked). The correct matrix is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} .$$

Answer (score 1):

The same happens with 4 and 6. The matrix is probably based on a different labeling of the graph (try exchanging 5 and 6).